# How to use perl-style replacement expressions in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am building a .NET text formatting component which uses a list of configurable regexes to transform input text.  I need to allow case conversion using regex rules as well, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in .NET.  A perl-style replacement expression such as s/(\b)([a-z])/\1\u\2/g would do the trick, but .NET doesn't seem to support it.  I know I can use MatchEvaluator with a delegate, but I need my replacement rules to be configurable (text).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The most .NET-style way would be

```
 var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<first>.*?):(?<second>.*)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
 Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace("moon:glow", "${second}:${first}"));
```

Will print

```
 glow:moon
```

You can also use ordinal references, like so:

```
 Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace("moon:glow", "$2:$1"));
```

Mixing them is ok.

In contrast to Perl you can individually retrieve all matched values for repeated atoms, like e.g.:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^((?<token>.*?):)*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (Capture token in regex
         .Match("moon:glow:is:the most:beautiful:thing")
         .Groups["token"].Captures)
     Console.WriteLine(token.Value);
```

Output

```
moon
glow
is
the most
beautiful
```

To get sophisticated match evaluation, you'd do e.g.

```
var upper = Regex.Replace("moon:glow:is:the most:beautiful:thing", "(.*?)(:|$)",                  
    m => m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() + m.Groups[2]);
Console.WriteLine(upper);
```

Unfortunately, I see no easy way to configure such a evaluation function as text only (except when using Compiler as a service, which I know is available on Mono, but I'm not quite sure on MS .Net yet)

Comment: how should OP translate this into a generic way to accept a userdefined replacement definition in his app. Your example does a switch. His example modifies case.

Comment: +1 Like OP and you I don't think it is straightforward to provide a user interface for generic specification of a replacement which will be conducted by a C# RegEx.

Comment: I may have been unclear in my original post.  I know how to use regex in .NET; I would like to know how to do case-conversion with the replacement parameter. In Perl this can be done, but in .NET it seems as though you can't do any logic in the replacement value.

Comment: `can't do any logic` might just be overly harsh, but yes, the caseconversion is a no-can-do